# PHP Regex - Get text between <P> tags with multiple lines

Tags: php, regex

I'm stuck on this one - trying to access data from some email HTML.

I get get all the single line of info - for example

```
(?<=<P>Phone: )(.*)(?=<\/P>)
```

will get me the the phone number from:

```
    <P>Name: Warren Warren</P>
    <P>Email: warren@warren.com</P>
    <P>Phone: (03) 1234 7777</P>
    <P>Comments1:
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce aliquet purus ac ullamcorper condimentum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
    </P>
    <P>Comments2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce aliquet purus ac ullamcorper condimentum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla nec orci magna. Quisque facilisis aliquet massa eu feugiat. Mauris eleifend elit aliquet mi egestas, eu gravida augue tempus. Sed libero nunc, euismod non nisl nec, vehicula laoreet dolor. Suspendisse sed convallis diam, non porta arcu. </P>

<div class="legal" style="color:#888;margin-top:140px;font-size:12px">
    <p>Footer Text</p>
```

Working copy here: https://regex101.com/r/6OZTO1/4

But I can't work out how to get the text from Comments1. I don't know enough about regex re multi-line modifiers and things like that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks - the solution in that question was around the "non-greedy" match. No idea what that means, but I will soon :)

Comment: (?<=<P>Comments1:)(.*?)(?=<\/P>)/s

Comment: For your specific pattern, just add the `s` flag and change your `.*` to non-greedy like `.*?`.